# Is there a method to sum all values in list of dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a list of `dict` like:

```
liste = [{"label": "hello", "value":12} , {"label": "hello", "value": 2},{"label": "world", "value": 21} ]
```

I want to sum according to `"label": "hello"` , so we will sum 12+2.

I want to have in output a list :

```
liste =  [{"label": "hello", "value": 14},{"label": "world", "value": 21}]
```

Comment: You can iterate through the list, check each dict for the right label and add value to a variable.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
val = sum([item['value'] for item in liste if item['label']=='hello'])
final = [item for item in liste if item['label']!='hello']
final.append({'label':'hello', 'value':val})

print(final)
```

Output:
`[{'label': 'world', 'value': 21}, {'label': 'hello', 'value': 14}]`

Answer (score 0):

It actually is an easy problem. You can iterate in the dictionary and check for the `label` and if it satisfies your condition you can add to a variable:

```
the_sum = 0

for item in liste:
    if item["label"] == "hello":
        the_sum += item["value"]

print(the_sum)
```

Or you can use list comprehensions, create the list of values which has the `label` of `hello` and use `sum` to sum all of them:

```
the_sum = sum([item["value"] for item in liste if item["label"] == "hello"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby` and a dict/list comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby
out = [{'label': name, 'value': sum(d['value'] for d in g)}
       for name,g in groupby(liste, lambda x: x['label'])]
```

output:

```
>>> out
[{'label': 'a', 'value': 14}, {'label': 'a', 'value': 21}]
```

Comment: This works, but there is aan error in the name of a variable. Try :
`out = [{'label': i, 'value': sum(d['value'] for d in g)} for i,g in groupby(liste, lambda x: x['label'])]`